# ASP.NET Label Control - Don't encode HTML

Tags: asp.net

I know this is an XSS risk but for my sepcific scenario am willing to accept it.

I want to use an ASP.NET label control in suh a way that I give it some HTML and it renders it as html without being encoded.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you directly use [Label.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text(v=vs.110).aspx), it doesn't encode the value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **Literal** Control instead of Label

Comment: However, a Literal doesn't allow you to apply a CSSclass to it.  Still the best solution though.

Comment: I had to switch `Literal.Mode` property to `Encode` to make this work (not the default).

Comment: @tigrou You had to switch it to `Encode` mode in order to *not* encode the value?

Comment: Default mode is Transform so if it requires Encode it needs to be changed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try `Server.HtmlDecode()` and `Server.HtmlEncode()` functions to change the way HTML is displayed on your page.