# asp.net onserverclick is not firing from stringbuilder string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating dynamic html botton with the following code

in Aspx.cs

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<button onserverclick='FancyBtn_Click' runat='server' id='BUTTON2'><b><i>PrintPdf</i></b></button>");
            Label2.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

protected void FancyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Great!!!";
    }
```

This is code is not working from c# code, If I write in aspx page then it works.

in Aspx

```
<button onserverclick='FancyBtn_Click' runat='server' id='BUTTON2'><b><i>PrintPdf</i></b></button>
```

Comment: Label by default encode the HTML - use Literal instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202984/asp-net-label-control-dont-encode-html

Comment: You are trying to dynamically add a ASP.NET control, this (or the use of Literal) wont work. You need to create the button and add it to a PlaceHolder. See here for an example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbbhe6w(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Using Label or Literal, page is showing button , but it is not firing the function